# Is mousemove event fire once in per frame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, mouseevent, dom-events

In this [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/JoeZheng/uy9poL1j/), press and move the mouse will draw the dot according to the mouse's position. The draw method is listen to `mousemove` callback, but it draw the discrete dot which show that the `mousemove` event is not fired continuously.

What is more, I collect the `event.timeStamp` and log in console. I found that the offset between adjacent event is near 16.7ms. So is `mousemove` event fire once in per frame?

Comment: Just to add a data point, I have exactly 60 mouse move events on a 60 Hz monitor on both Firefox and Chromium on Gnome on Arch Linux, which is really problematic if you want to do high quality painting in a browser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `mousemove` event frequency is implementation specific, and not defined by any specification.

> A user agent MUST dispatch this event when a pointing device is moved while it is over an element. The frequency rate of events while the pointing device is moved is implementation-, device-, and platform-specific, but multiple consecutive mousemove events SHOULD be fired for sustained pointer-device movement, rather than a single event for each instance of mouse movement. Implementations are encouraged to determine the optimal frequency rate to balance responsiveness with performance.
>
> -- [UI Events, W3C Working Draft, 04 August 2016](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-type-mousemove)

It's entirely possible some browsers on some platforms will limit it to once per-frame. There is no guarantee any browser that may do this will continue to do so however.

If you want to draw a continuous line, you would need to create interpolation data between each two points.